# my data passed through activities isn't saving?

Tags: java, android

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong? or if once the found the solution to the problem, can you please explain what i did wrong and thanks.

**CODE SOURCE**

```
 final Button nameActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameActivity);
 nameActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         userFirstName = firstName.getText().toString();
         userLastName = lastName.getText().toString();
         Intent nameIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NameActivity.class);
         Bundle nameInfoBundle = new Bundle();
         nameInfoBundle.putString(States.STATE_FIRSTNAME, userFirstName);
         nameInfoBundle.putString(States.STATE_LASTNAME, userLastName);
         startActivity(nameIntent);
     }
 });
```

Comment: If you are just looking for a simple way to persist the data you can use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: but why what I wrote, doesn't save the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Intent nameIntent = new Intent();
    nameIntent.putExtra(States.STATE_FIRSTNAME, userFirstName);
    nameIntent.putExtra(States.STATE_LASTNAME, userLastName);
```

And in NameActivity's onCreate() method use this to retrieve the values:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String userFirstName = intent.getExtras(States.STATE_FIRSTNAME);
    String userLastName = intent.getExtras(States.STATE_LASTNAME);
```

Comment: But I wan't to save the information of the fields after activity is killed

Comment: I dont get what you're trying to say

Comment: the goal is  to save the information previously from the inputted fields.

Comment: What is the goal?

Comment: So store it in a variable in whichever activity you are going to

Comment: but doesn't the "Bundle" object handle that for me ?

Comment: If you want to save data and retain even after the app has been restarted, you MUST use SharedPreferences  like in the below answer. The Bundle object you are creating, along with all other data in the app will be gone once the app has been closed, unless you use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to presist data when the app has been killed.

Save the data to the `SharedPreferences` you can do this.

```
private void saveDataToSharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString(States.STATE_FIRSTNAME, userFirstName);
    edit.putString(States.STATE_LASTNAME, userLastName);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Now you can do this to retreive the data:

```
private void retrieveDataFromSharedPreferences() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String firstName = pref.getString(States.STATE_FIRSTNAME);
        String lastName = pref.getString(States.STATE_LASTNAME);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What you were doing is saving the data in the `Intent` and passing it to the `Activity`. The data will be kept in the `Intent` only as long as the app is active--it is not saved.

Comment: ahm so the bundle object there, was that useless? not being used at all? please let me know and thank you so much this helped me

Comment: You can use the bundle to pass data--for example to another `Activity` as you did in your code above. `SharedPreferences` are used to persist data even after the app is no longer in memory, but they are not great for passing data to another `Activity`--especially when combined with `.commit()` because it is an asynchronous method. This means the data might not be available, when the other `Activity` goes through the `onCreate` method